# Issue Loading Flat File in SSIS - Invalid Character on Last Line

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I am trying to import a flat file to a table in SSIS but its throwing an error because theres a "SUB" character on the last line.  How can i get around this or remove it?  Please see the screen shot below to see what i see in notepad++.  When i remove it it works fine.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a conditional split on your data flow and route your unusable rows out of your destination.

Reference-- (MSDN) http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=en-US&k=k(sql12.dts.designer.conditionalsplittrans.f1)&rd=true

Comment: I looks at this but i dont know the value of whatever that SUB character is so it wasnt working.

Comment: if there is an expected format for the first(or any other) column of your document you could program for that format rather than a specific value and if the row does not meet those criteria they will be sorted to unusable.